# How to check the barcode is 1D or 2D or 3D(QR code)?

Tags: vb.net, barcode

I am using the following code to get the barcode data.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42852/Reading-Barcodes-from-an-Image-III?msg=5052241#xx5052241xx

But i don't know how to get the barcode type which means the barcode is 1D or 2D or 3D(QR code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above library can't read 2D Barcodes anyway, only some 1D barcodes.
There are no 3D Barcodes until now (aren't there?), QR is a 2D Code.
I would use a better library like Zxing or zbar for barcode decoding, they will have a much better success rate and will tell you the type of barcode they did decode.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Does any open source available to read the barcode vlue and bar code type?

Comment: Yes, the ones I mentioned: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/ and https://github.com/zxing/zxing . Both will give you the value and type of detected barcode. There is a C# port of zxing, therefore it might be easier to integrate into an vb.net project.

Comment: Thanks so much. here barcode type means not 1D or 2D correct?

Comment: @mail2vguna don't forget to flag as accepted answer then.